# Etymology vs. ethymology

Tags: word-choice, orthography

Merriam-webster lists the word *etymology* but not *ethymology*. Is the latter spelling wrong, or is it used in some regional variation?

Comment: Very interesting: when searching for etymology on Google, it comes up with 6,000,000 results; but when searching for ethymology, it comes up with 14,100,000 results (done on 22.11.2013). This means that more people write this word incorrectly than correctly. So much for crowd sourcing... :)

Comment: You are too quick to jump to conclusions, as Google numbers are notoriously unreliable. Different people get different numbers, and the numbers can change drastically from one results page to the next. Case in point, I get 5,200,000 results for *ethymology*, not 14,000,000, and on page 25 it suddenly drops to 245. That's right, 25 pages of results is *all* I actually get. The millions are complete humbug. We've covered this before, and for many search strings we saw the number drop dramatically as soon as on page 2. Check it out with a few queries and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes even the apparently easiest questions are treacherous, but I've never seen the other variant, I've even searched it in 3 dictionaries to be 100% sure, and couldn't find anything; the word is *Etymology*.

This is the etymology for Etymology:

> ORIGIN late Middle English: from Old French ethimologie, via Latin from Greek **etumologia**, from **etumologos** ‘*student of etymology*’, from ***etumon***, neuter singular of etumos ‘*true*.’

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Of course. But even the [Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ethymology) redirects to Etymology. I've searched the Oxford English Dictionary, Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary and the New Oxford American Dictionary.

Comment: +1 The OED doesn't recognize *ethymology*, and I've never seen it; it is safe to assume that it will be considered a simple spelling mistake by 99 % of people. Just don't use it.

Comment: Perhaps "ethymology" occurs with such frequency because it is a possible misspelling for three words: etymology, ethnology and entomology.